# Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser

Tags: jquery, safari, google-chrome, webkit, browser-detection

It seems [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is able to identify webkit rather easily as of 1.4.  But how can I use it to distinguish Chrome from Safari (and visa-versa)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since Sarfraz has not corrected his answer (thank you Sarfraz for pointing me in the correct direction), I will post functioning code here.

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

// Is this a version of Chrome?
if($.browser.chrome){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('chrome/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  $.browser.version = userAgent;
  // If it is chrome then jQuery thinks it's safari so we have to tell it it isn't
  $.browser.safari = false;
}

// Is this a version of Safari?
if($.browser.safari){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('version/') +8);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  $.browser.version = userAgent;
}
```

Comment: For safari, $.browser.version ends up giving you the version of webkit, not the version of safari. Try userAgent.indexOf('Version/') + 8 instead.

Comment: Also, you could substring until a space character instead of period on the lines that say `userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));` in order to get full version numbers rather than just the first part of the version number (the Major number).

Comment: @David, you would need to do lowercase `v` in your `'Version/'` string, as earlier in the code the user agent string was lowercased.

Answer (score 38):

**Without** jQuery

```
isChrome = function() { 
  return /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
}
isSafari = function() {
  return /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
}
```

---

**With** jQuery

(Following will not work with jQuery 1.9 and above as `jQuery.browser` has been removed from jQuery. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

```
$.browser.chrome = $.browser.webkit && !!window.chrome;
$.browser.safari = $.browser.webkit && !window.chrome;
```

Comment: first solution is very elegant.

Comment: Why !! for chrome what is that mean ?

Comment: It's very sad that $.browser was removed. But how do we detect that since 1.10? I didn't see anything in the API documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like:

```
// Is this a version of Chrome?
if($.browser.chrome){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('chrome/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  version = userAgent;
  // If it is chrome then jQuery thinks it's safari so we have to tell it it isn't
  $.browser.safari = false;
}

// Is this a version of Safari?

if($.browser.safari){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('safari/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  version = userAgent;
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: uhm -- $.browser.chrome is undefined. and $.browser.safari is true for both chrome and safari

Comment: @sAc, you were close, this should appear before the code you provided: `var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); var version = 0;`

Comment: @sAc, also, the `version` variable is unneeded, and should be replaced with `$.browser.version`.

Comment: @sAc, I'd like to accept your answer, as it put me on the right track – but am unable to do so as long as it contains non-operable code. Please edit your answer to correct the errors mentioned above.

Comment: @kingjeffrey: I posted the code from jquery docs for which link is posted in my answer, it was not written by me. And any fixes are already mentioned in these comments :)

Comment: @sAc, you pasted a portion of the code that lost significant context. While it pointed me in the right direction, this loss of context cripples the provided code. I'd edit it myself, except I do not allowed by my reputation.

Answer (score 2):

```
/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also for non-JQuery users:

```
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('WebKit') + 1 ? 
       ((navigator.vendor || '').indexOf('Apple') + 1 ? /* Safari */ : /* Chrome */)
    : /* not Webkit */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HtWag/13/

Comment: This did the trick for me. It's a bit of a trick to read through if you aren't used to this kind of conditional statement, but you laid it out quite well.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this approach as well, it works for me.

```
    isSafari: function () 
    {
            var isSafari = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1
                        && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)

            console.log('IsSafari : ' + isSafari);

            return isSafari;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.chrome?$.browser.chrome=!0:($.browser.webkit&&($.browser.safari=!0),$.browser.chrome=!1);
```

This patch adds **$.browser.chrome** and also exclude Goolge Chrome detection from **$.browser.safari**