# How to detect if a browser is Chrome using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-selectors, cross-browser

I have a bit of an issue with a function running in chrome that works properly in Safari, both webkit browsers...

I need to customize a variable in a function for Chrome, but not for Safari.

Sadly, I have been using this to detect if it is a webkit browser:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
```

But I need to detect:

```
if ($.browser.chrome) {
```

Is there any way to write a similar statement (a working version of the one above)?

Comment: Maybe you could post the broken function to see if we can help you get it working in chrome too?

Comment: The function is rather long and I know how to fix it, I just need to be able to customize it for Chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser

Comment: That is a good idea though, I just feel like I have worked through it enough to know where the issue is

Comment: Haim, thank you. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

if($.browser.chrome){
  ............

}
```

**UPDATE:(10x to @Mr. Bacciagalupe)**

jQuery has removed `$.browser` from **1.9** and their latest release.

But you can still use $.browser as a standalone plugin, found [here](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin)

Comment: @TaylorMac I'm not sure why it works much better than the others since the first link I posted has the same example in the 5th comment and the second link also uses the same technique but shows you how the others are detected also. Anyway I'm glad you found your solution.

Comment: Chromium also includes "Chrome" in its User-Agent, but why not `/chrom(e|ium)/` just to be safe :)

Comment: jQuery api docs recommend AGAINST using $.browser. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ ..  also better to use feature detection than checking browser user agent that can be spoofed.. $.browser tests for user agent.. the jQuery api says to use $.support.. but in this case try testing if window.chrome exists..

Comment: Fails on IE8 as it lists chromeframe:
mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 8.0; windows nt 5.1; trident/4.0; chromeframe/25.0.1364.97; .net clr 1.1.4322; .net clr 2.0.50727; infopath.1; ms-rtc lm 8; .net4.0c; .net4.0e; .net clr 3.0.4506.2152; .net clr 3.5.30729)

Comment: @PAPAFRESH, unfortunately sometimes there is no feature available to differentiate compatibility. For example, I just had to use this because of browser differences with `position()` when the offset parent has a border.

Comment: @Jacob, jQuery has removed $.browser from 1.9 and their latest release. But you can still use $.browser as a standalone plugin, found here: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Comment: jQuery.browser is deprecated now. do we have an alternative solution now.

Answer (score 46):

```
if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
 alert('I am chrome');
}
```

Comment: this is detected in IE Edge

Answer (score 12):

This question was already discussed here: [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618)

Please try this:

```
var isChromium = window.chrome;
if(isChromium){
    // is Google chrome 
} else {
    // not Google chrome 
}
```

But a more complete and accurate answer would be this since IE11, IE Edge, and Opera will also return `true` for `window.chrome`

So use the below:

```
// please note, 
// that IE11 now returns undefined again for window.chrome
// and new Opera 30 outputs true for window.chrome
// but needs to check if window.opr is not undefined
// and new IE Edge outputs to true now for window.chrome
// and if not iOS Chrome check
// so use the below updated condition
var isChromium = window.chrome;
var winNav = window.navigator;
var vendorName = winNav.vendor;
var isOpera = typeof window.opr !== "undefined";
var isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
var isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

if (isIOSChrome) {
   // is Google Chrome on IOS
} else if(
  isChromium !== null &&
  typeof isChromium !== "undefined" &&
  vendorName === "Google Inc." &&
  isOpera === false &&
  isIEedge === false
) {
   // is Google Chrome
} else { 
   // not Google Chrome 
}
```

Above posts advise to use jQuery.browser. **But the jQuery API recommends against using this method**.. (see [DOCS in API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)). And states its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery.

The jQuery API recommends to use [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/).

The reason being is that 'jQuery.browser' uses the user agent which can be spoofed and it is actually deprecated in later versions of jQuery.  If you really want to use $.browser.. Here is the link to the standalone jQuery plugin, since it has been removed from jQuery version 1.9.1. https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

It's better to use feature object detection instead of browser detection.

Also if you use the Google Chrome inspector and go to the console tab. Type 'window' and press enter. Then you be able to view the DOM properties for the 'window object'. When you collapse the object you can view all the properties, including the 'chrome' property.

I hope this helps, even though the question was how to do with with jQuery. But sometimes straight javascript is more simple!

Answer (score 9):

User Endless is right,

```
$.browser.chrome = (typeof window.chrome === "object");
```

code is best to detect Chrome browser using jQuery.

If you using IE and added GoogleFrame as plugin then

```
var is_chrome = /chrome/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );
```

code will treat as Chrome browser because GoogleFrame plugin modifying the navigator property and adding chromeframe inside it.

Answer (score 5):

```
var is_chrome = /chrome/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );
```

Answer (score 5):

userAgent can be changed. for more robust, use the global variable specified by chrome

```
$.browser.chrome = (typeof window.chrome === "object");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(navigator.vendor.indexOf('Goog') > -1){
  //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not Jquery , I use jquery myself but for browser detection I have used  the script on [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) a few times. It detects all major browsers, *and then some*. The work is pretty much all done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly due to Opera's latest update `!!window.chrome` (and other tests on the window object) when testing in Opera returns true.

Conditionizr takes care of this for you and solves the Opera issue:

```
conditionizr.add('chrome', [], function () {
    return !!window.chrome && !/opera|opr/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
});
```

I'd highly suggest using it as none of the above are now valid.

This allows you to do:

```
if (conditionizr.chrome) {...}
```

[Conditionizr](http://conditionizr.com) takes care of other browser detects and is much faster and reliable than jQuery hacks.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick addition, and I'm surprised nobody has thought of this, you could use the `in` operator:

```
"chrome" in window
```

Obviously this isn't using JQuery, but I figured I'd put it since it's handy for times when you aren't using any external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

When I test the answer @IE, I got always "true". The better way is this which works also @IE:

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
```

As described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565120/1201725