# how to add chrome specific css to if statement

Tags: jquery

what is the proper way to make this work , its not targeting chrome with a different height

```
        if(franchise_id=="0000") {
          $('#aj_auction').css('height', '558px');
            if($.browser.chrome) {
              $('#aj_auction').css('height', '598px');
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a browser is Chrome using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339480/how-to-detect-if-a-browser-is-chrome-using-jquery)

Comment: saw that , but how would i do a if statement within this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  **$.browser.chrome** to check browser

```
if(franchise_id=="0000") {
  if($.browser.chrome) {
      $('#aj_auction').css('height', '598px');
  }else{

      $('#aj_auction').css('height', '558px'); 

 }
}
```

Need to use Modernizr.

However, if you necessarily want to use $.browser property, you can do it using [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin (for JQuery >= 1.9 - in earlier versions you can just use it)

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's chrome using `userAgent`

```
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    if(is_chrome){
        $('#aj_auction').css('height', '598px');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to detect the browser first and apply that condition as follows :

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 
if($.browser.chrome){
........
}
```

jQuery has removed $.browser from 1.9 and their latest release.But we can still use $.browser as a standalone plugin,[link](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin).

Hope this helps.