# jQuery(window).focus in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net

it seems that the `window.focus` event does not trigger in Chrome.

```
 jQuery(window).focus(function () {
    //your logic
});
```

It works on both IE and FF. I read somewhere that blur may be an alternative for this in Chrome. If thats true, how do I make sure it runs only for Chrome. I don't want this logic to run twice on both IE and FF.

**Update:** Based on one anwser below, I can probably detect the browser, but it still does not seem to work with the blur event. Anyone knows what I can use in chrome corresponding to the focus event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).bind('focus', function () {
    // your logic .
});
```

if you use bind, it seems to work fine in chrome as well. I'm using this in a `modalpopupcontainer` which makes it more complex. Anyway, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Read this post it will show you how tell which browser the user is using:

[Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser)

If a problem is in chrome then in most cases it's a webkit problem (safari aswell) so you could do a condition to check the browser:

```
 if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //webkit code here
 } else {
    //normal code here
 }
```