# Distinguish between chrome and safari with real version numbers?

Tags: browser, version, blocking

I tried the solution in [Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser) but it doesnt work. This solution does but i dont have any way of getting the real version numbers:

```
$.browser.chrome = $.browser.webkit && !!window.chrome;
$.browser.safari = $.browser.webkit && !window.chrome;
```

I need to detect the full version numbers so that i can block older versions of these (because their slow/buggy, not for features).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use straight Javascript:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('Chrome'))
{
  var n=navigator.userAgent.split(" ");
  var curVersion="";
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
  {
     if(n[i].indexOf("Chrome"))
     {
        curVersionTmp=n[i].split("/");
        curVersion = curVersionTmp[1];   
     }
  }
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('applewebkit'))
{
  var n=navigator.userAgent.split(" ");
  var curVersion="";
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
  {
     if(n[i].indexOf("Version"))
     {
        curVersionTmp=n[i].split("/");
        curVersion = curVersionTmp[1];   
     }
  }
}
```

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/

Comment: And how is that supposed to reveal the real version number?

Comment: It's supposed to tell if you're using chrome or safari (that's what your code looks like it's doing)

Comment: although there are code numbers appended to the end of the string in the website

Comment: thats the webkit engine, not the browser version.

Comment: so for example, Safari 5.1.3 says Version/5.1.3 in the useragent, 5.1 says Version/5.1

Comment: yeah, and putting a if (is_chrome <100) {alert "chrome"} doesnt do anything, because it reports the webkit engine number of 500+

Comment: 543 is webkit build for example Safari/534.53.10 would mean webkit build 543.53.10

Comment: you should take a look at your link, 534.53.10 is the version that jquery uses to qualify not version 5.1.3 of safari

Comment: OK, so you dont know how to answer the question, anyone know how to actually detect the real browser version number, because jquery obviously doesnt.