# $.browser does not work correctly for Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to use `$.browser` in my script, but it doesn't work as I want. For example, in Chrome it has properties `safari` and `webkit` set to `true`.

Why does this happen?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkjW4/).

Comment: Simply because Chrome *is* a webkit browser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it happened because your fiddle use `jQuery 1.7.2` in this release you can find:

```
// Deprecated, use jQuery.browser.webkit instead
if ( jQuery.browser.webkit ) {
    jQuery.browser.safari = true;
}
```

Both browsers `chrome` and `safari` are based on webkit.

**Solutions:**

1. You can update jQuery. Like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkjW4/1/).
2. You can use advices from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) like:

   ```
   $.browser.chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1;
   $.browser.safari = ( $.browser.safari && /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) ) ? false : true;
   ```

You can watch this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkjW4/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Probably 'cause that's part of Chrome's user agent. See here:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

What you probably need might be answered in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364740/50109).