# $.browser.safari = false breaks $.scrollTo in Safari and Chrome (webkit)

Tags: jquery, scrollto

This isn't entirely scientific, but if I set $.browser.safari = false in Safari or Chrome, then $.scrollTo no longer works on any element with any parameters. It doesn't throw an error or anything, but it certainly doesn't scroll.

I noticed this problem after following this advice: [Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser)

Comment: There's a big difference between `$.browser.safari = false` and `$.browser.safari == false`. The former assigns, the latter compares.

Comment: `$.browser.safari` is meant to be read or compared, NOT set.  When you set it, you run the risk of messing up other code that uses it.

Comment: Can you point me to some reference on why not to set $.browser.safari? I only ask because there are code examples that use it and I can't seem to understand why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set $.browser.safari = false in Safari/Chrome while using jQuery ScrollTo.