# How detect Safari browser ONLY on desktop?

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari, mobile-safari, navigator

How detect `Safari` browser ONLY on desktop ?
I want to know only when user is on desktop and not with mobile device.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
    //find safari
}
```

I noticed that Desktop Safari doesn't support `input[type=date]` but mobile safari (the name is webkit ?) yes. 
So for me is important understand when user is on desktop.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: @StefanBlamberg how can be duplicate if in "your question" is how detect mobile device with jquery while in my quesion how detect only desktop safari ?!

Comment: I am a bit confused, why can't you use the answers provided there to make sure that it is not a mobile safari version? e.g. `if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // mobile!
}` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24600597/5843525

Comment: Are you only wanting to target the Safari browser; mobile vs desktop? Are you expecting Windows and Mac users or just one or something else?

Comment: for me is impostant to know only if is desktop safari, because i have an input type date and safari (on desktop) doesn't support it https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: @Borja Please don't abuse comment flags, nothing here *remotely* qualifies as "harassment, bigotry or abuse".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const uA = navigator.userAgent;
const vendor = navigator.vendor;
if (/Safari/i.test(uA) && /Apple Computer/.test(vendor) && !/Mobi|Android/i.test(uA)) {
  //Desktop Safari
}
```

Comment: chrome has Safari in its user agent and will be detected with this

Comment: @P.Scheit Thanks for pointing this out, I updated the answer according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser